# VBO on OpenGL ES 2.0 Not Showing Anything

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vbo, vertex-buffer

I am learning OpenGL ES . I have successfully drawn some cubes, understanding basic matrices logic behind for camera location, etc. Right now I am trying to build an example for VBO but It is not drawn anything into the screen. I will paste my code, probably someone could realize what I am doing wrong.

#### Fragment Shader Code

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec3 v_colour; 
uniform sampler2D s_texture;    
void main() 
{ 
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
}
```

#### Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec3 av3position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord; 
attribute vec3 av3colour;

uniform mat4 PerspectiveMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texCoord; 
varying vec3 v_colour;

void main() 
{ 
v_texCoord = a_texCoord; 
v_colour =av3colour;
vec4 pos = ModelViewMatrix * vec4(av3position,1.0);
gl_Position = PerspectiveMatrix * pos;
}
```

#### Texture Loading

```
Texture01RGBA->boLoadTextureFromfile("BitmapData/cubeLayout_02.png" );

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);         // Use tightly packed data
glGenTextures(1, &gluiTextureID);              // Generate a texture object
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gluiTextureID);   // Bind the texture object
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Texture01RGBA->getWidth(), Texture01RGBA->getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Texture01RGBA->getPixmapPointer()); 
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);     
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, gluiTextureID );
// Set the sampler texture unit to 0
glUniform1i ( iLoc2DSampler, 0 );
```

#### Vertex Object Structure

```
const float aCubeVertices[] =
{ // x, y, z, nx, ny, nz, u, v
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 0.500000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 0.250000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.250000, 0.250000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.250000, 0.500000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 0.750000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.250000, 0.750000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.250000, 1.000000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 1.000000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.750000, 0.250000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.750000, 0.000000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.250000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.250000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.000000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.250000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.250000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.000000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.750000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.500000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.500000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.250000, 0.750000
};

unsigned short aCubeIndices[]= // 36 Elements. 3 Groups
{  0,1,2,0,2,3,4,5,6,4,6,7,8,9,10,8,10,11,12,13,14,12,14,15,16,17,18,16,18,19,20,21,22,20,22,23 };
```

#### VBO Creation

```
glGenBuffers (1, &vao);
glBindBuffer  (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float)*8, aCubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &vinx);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vinx);

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36* sizeof(GLushort), aCubeIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

#### VBO Drawing

```
glBindBuffer  (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao);
  // set up vertex attributes
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(iLocPosition);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(iLocTexCoord);
  glVertexAttribPointer(iLocPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*8, 0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(iLocTexCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*8,  (const void *)24  );
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vinx);
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(iLocPosition);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(iLocTexCoord);
```

As I pointed out before I have been using basically the same code for previous more simple examples I've done (textures,transformation matrices). I have also checked for errors with and no code error is  present.

I will appreciate if someone highlight what could be wrong with my code.

Comment: Looks to me like you've pretty much got the right idea, nothing is jumping out at me as incorrect. If you switch from VBO to using basic vertex arrays (no gl*Buffer), does that work for you? It might help if you can identify exactly where your code stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Your vertex buffer (or at least your index buffer) seems incorrect. For instance, the first triangle is defined by the indices 0, 1, 2, which correspond to the following vertices:

```
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 0.500000,
 1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.500000, 0.250000,
-1.000000,1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.250000, 0.250000,
```

As you can see, the position of the first and the second vertices is the same (1,1,1). The result is a degenerate triangle (a triangle with no area) which can't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show here looks correct. The problem could be in other parts of the code. One source of error could be how you setup your modelview and perspective matrix. Another might be something wrong with the way you set your uniforms glUniform*() (perhaps a row/column majority mismatch with your matrices and how OpenGL expects it). If you could paste that code then we would have the complete picture
I assume the vertex and index data for the cube is correct since you mentioned that you already got cubes drawn before.